# React: Displaying images from api call

Tags: reactjs, image, webpack

I'm trying to display the images at I get from an api call. I'm getting:

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '"https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/gw8AAOSwgsxagkvP/s-l225.jpg"'

Without require, I'm not getting a warning, but nothing is rendering.

console logging the pic variable below displays:
"https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/gw8AAOSwgsxagkvP/s-l225.jpg"

I've read that I need to import the pics, but don't know how I should execute that.

```
class SingleItem extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}
render(){
    const { image: imageUrl  } = this.props.value;
    let img = Object.values(imageUrl).toString()
    let pic = `"${img}"`
    var image = require(pic)
    return (
        <div>
            <div src={image}></div>
        </div>
    )
   }
 }

export default SingleItem;
```

Comment: You have a `div` rather than an `img`. Could that be the problem? Also, you won’t need require for absolute urls.

Comment: Jeez..<img> was it.  Thanks

Comment: No problem. Happy it helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you requiring the image.

Just use the image url for the src attribute

```
render(){
    const { image: imageUrl  } = this.props.value;
    let img = Object.values(imageUrl).toString()
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={img}></img>
        </div>
    )
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `require` the image. Just set the `imageUrl` as the `src` attribute.

You also need to modify the `div` tag to an `img` tag.

The following should work great:

```
class SingleItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        const { image: imageUrl } = this.props.value;
        let img = Object.values(imageUrl).toString()

        return ( 
            <div>
                <img src = {img}/> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SingleItem;
```